# Redirect to last session and no need login ( prevent auto logout)

Tags: php, session, cookies, logout

I have some input form in my web. But before that I need to login first so I can direct to input page.

At the last time, if my PC crash then turn on again my chromium browser will show restore button. And after click it,my last page will return and no need login any more.

But Why for now I can't do that even i have clicked the button.

This my php script in my input page:

```
<?php
session_start(); //Start the session
if(isset($_SESSION["loguser"])){
//if(!session_is_registered("loguser")){ //If session not registered
header("location:login.php"); // Redirect to login.php page
}
else //Continue to current page
header( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' );
?>
```

What i want to do is how to make my page become no need to login if I don't logout.
How to make cookies expire just if we hit logout button?

thanks.

Comment: Fyi, `session_is_registered(...)` is deprecated, use `isset($_SESSION[...])` instead.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: how if session is not registered?

Comment: @nunu: is_registered has nothing to do with whether you've started the session or not. It's basically an oldschool method of doing `isset($_SESSION['somevar'])`, and as of 5.3, should not be used anymore.

Comment: ok I'm understand now, but my problem if I go for long time my page become auto log out. and if my pc crash i can't back to last page, should be log in again. and last input are gone.

Comment: well then, you need cookies for this. [Look here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php)

Comment: @D-Lo: how to add `setcookies()` so i can avoid this page become auto logout?

Comment: It's all in the manual I link on my previous comment. Initially, you need to replace your `$_SESSION['loguser'];` to `setcookie("loguser", $value);` then you can now test if cookie is set `if(isset($_COOKIE["loguser"]))`, just make sure you assign `$value` with the value you assigned on `$_SESSION["loguser"]`

Answer (score 0):

! is missed out in the if condition.(Can you check?)

```
if(isset($_SESSION["loguser"])){
//if(!session_is_registered("loguser")){ //If session not registered
header("location:login.php"); // Redirect to login.php page
}
```

Should be

```
if(!isset($_SESSION["loguser"])){
//if(!session_is_registered("loguser")){ //If session not registered
header("location:login.php"); // Redirect to login.php page
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i change like this:

```
<?php
session_start(); //Start the session
setcookie("loguser");
if(!isset($_COOKIE["loguser"])){
     header("location:login.php"); // Redirect to login.php page
     }
else { //Continue to current page
     header( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' );
     }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set the cookie right before you check if the cookie is set then the if statement will never fire or behave as expected.
You should set the cookie under your login.php like with a expiry in the future:

```
setcookie("loguser","John Doe",time()+60*60*24*30);  //Expires in 30days
```

Otherwise the cookie is treated like a session variable and is thrown away as soon as the session is closed.

For safety reasons you should then also check the cookie value with something in your DB since the value of a cookie can easily be read and changed on the user's browser.